# When creating an XmlWriter in Visual Studio, I am given a compiler error that says it cannot convert from a string to to IO.Stream

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

There exists an overloaded constructor, however, that does accept a string and XmlWriterSettings as parameters. Any ideas on how to fix this?
According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlWriter_Create_System_String_System_Xml_XmlWriterSettings_), my arguments should be valid.

[image: Screenshot of error from Visual Studio]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce.  What version of .Net and System.Xml are you using?  You might also try closing and re-opening visual studio.

Comment: Using .NET Framework 4.6.1. System.Xml is 4.7.2 I think. I have tried closing and reopening as well as turning off and back on again. Same issue.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaannnd... it started working magically again after I git commit. Saved with code commented out, then uncommented after commit. Now it works. Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 0):

Started working again magically. Could be that I'm running Windows on Boot Camp. These issues pop up every once in a while.